# How to return token value after login to C# Soap Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-services, wcf, soap

**I have a soap(wsdl) service and need to call this service using c# and get a token value as a return. The connection to the service is established, but (resultdata) I get a NullReferenceException error without returning the token value.**

Am I making a mistake while calling the service, can you take a look???

```
public async Task WebServiceOpration()
{

    string xmlPostData =
    @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=url1 xmlns: aut=url2>" +
    "<soapenv:Header/>" +
    "<soapenv:Body>" +
    "<aut:authenticate>" +
    "<password>?</password>" +
    "<username>?</username>" +
    "</aut:authenticate>" +
    "</soapenv:Body>" +
    "</soapenv:Envelope>";
    xmlPostData = xmlPostData.Replace("url1", "\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"");
    xmlPostData = xmlPostData.Replace("url2", "\"http://authentication.ep.op.ws.tcell.imcp.enk.ericsson.com/\"");



    string Url = "wsdl adress";
    var resultData = string.Empty;
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);




    // Post edilecek Xml datası Byte dizisine çeviriliyor.
    byte[] byteArray;
    byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlPostData);
    //var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);


    //webRequest.UserAgent = ".NET";
    webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    webRequest.ContentType = " text/xml; encoding='utf-8' ";
    webRequest.Accept = "application/xml;odata=verbose";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;



    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlPostData))
    {
        using (Stream dataStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            await dataStream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        webRequest.ContentLength = 0;
    }



    using (WebResponse response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            resultData = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            string head = response.Headers.ToString();
            
            Console.WriteLine(head);
            //Console.WriteLine("Token :"  , resultData);
            
        }
    }
```

// This subsection was added later.

```
    authenticationResponse authenticationResponse = new authenticationResponse();
    string rscode = authenticationResponse.responseCode.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(rscode);
    var token = authenticationResponse.token.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(token);
```

Comment: An HTTP connection closes after each request/response (webrequest).  This is not like a TCP message that stays open.  You said "The connection to the service is established" which is not the case with HTTP since the connection closes.

Comment: No, I'm connecting, but the data I want is not getting back to me.

Comment: Do you get a response?  What status is in response?  200 OK is good and 400/500 is a error.

Comment: I am not getting any service related error. result data is empty. Normally, it should have a token value.

Comment: The data your are looking for is in the response of the body.  Normally you only get a body when the status is 200 OK.  Service Error doesn't necessarily mean good results.  A few things could be happening 1) The service is not finding the data that the request queried 2) The error may not get detected by the server 3) The serviced may detect the error and send back an error status.